# How do I add an IP address to a users dial in tab within powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell

How do I add an IP address to a users dial in tab within powershell.

I want to do it about a 100 times so I was hoping to use the ad cmdlets to perform the task reading from a csv file the account name and the ip address.

Does anybody know the property to set this?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: "dial in tab"...  Sorry, what version of Windows is this for?  Where can I find this tab exactly?

Answer (score 2):

To configure the "Assign a Static IP Address, you need to set the properties [msRADIUSFramedIPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678119(v=VS.85).aspx) and [msRASSavedFramedIPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678129(v=VS.85).aspx) properties, however it says on those pages that they are used internally and not to modify them directly.

The [RAS User Administration Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446729(v=VS.85).aspx) page may have some potential.

Answer (score 2):

I was needing to do something similar today and ended up using something like this:

```
PS C:\> $myip="192.168.1.254";$bytes=([IPAddress]$myip).GetAddressBytes();[Array]::Reverse($bytes);[BitConverter]::ToUInt32($bytes,0)
3232236030
PS C:\> $myip="3232236030";([system.net.ipaddress] $myip).ipaddresstostring
192.168.1.254
PS C:\>Set-ADUser -Identity jdoe -Add @{msRADIUSFramedIPAddress="3232236030"}
PS C:\>Set-ADUser -Identity jdoe -Remove @{msRADIUSFramedIPAddress="3232236030"}
```

Reading CSV input will vary according to how you format your CSV file, but PowerShell has something to help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to configuring Routing and Remote Access using powershell. A quick search finds this for setting [RRAS Dial-in Attribute using Powershell](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.windows.powershell/RRAS-Dial-In-Attribute) to query Active Directory and WMI.